# Send notification using Cloud Functions for Firebase to specific user

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I'm using Cloud Functions for Firebase to send notifications to the user. I'm able to get the notification but the problem is that everyone is getting the notification, I'm trying to send the notification to a particular user. I'm saving user's device id in Firebase's database and then send that particular person the notification. Here is my code:

To save user's data, which is actually working fine:

```
DatabaseReference root = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
            DatabaseReference groupsRef = root.child("users").child(Settings.Secure
            .getString(ctx.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID));
            groupsRef.child("isLogin").setValue(2);
```

In first activity subscribing to the topic:

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("android");
```

And finally javascript code(something I know very little about):

```
var functions = require('firebase-functions');
var admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('/users')
    .onWrite(event => {

    var eventSnapshot = event.data;
    var str = "This is notification"
    console.log(str);

    var topic = "android";
    var payload = {
        data: {
            isLogin: eventSnapshot.child("975af90b767584c5").child("isLogin").val()
        }
    };

    return admin.messaging().sendToTopic(topic, payload)
        .then(function (response) {
            // See the MessagingTopicResponse reference documentation for the
            // contents of response.
            console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log("Error sending message:", error);
        });
    });
```

Here instead of "975af90b767584c5" which is hardcoded right now, I want to send device id, which I don't know how to do in javascript. Or if there is any other way.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: you have to send notification to device TOKEN not ID

Comment: @DivyeshPatel How to do that in javascript?? Sorry but i don't know much js

Comment: when user register in app, you have to save device token in database, then fetch that token (where userid=?) from db and send notification to that token.

Comment: and you are currently send notification to topic(android) thats why everyone getting notifications

Comment: ok, so I'll save device token instead of device ID. But what changes I've to do in js? I'm still little confused

Comment: It would really help me if you could post an answer with a little brief and code, thanks. As I have little to none experience in js.

Comment: i do not know about javascript, but get token of single user and send notification data to that token

Answer (score 5):

First in app, get User FCM token by

```
String Token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
```

Now, send this token to your server and save it with other user details in Database.

Then when you want to send Notification to specific use, fetch that user's FCM token from Database via user id or something else.If you want to send notification to multiple user then fetch multiple user FCM token from database and put it in arrayList.

Now for main part,  call fcm endpoint with your KEY, notification content
and most important: token or token array.

In your case, do not use sendToTopic, use send to: Token/Array

You can google for java script syntax, but this is main logic.For more info:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/send-messages